# POST xml to .Net Core Web API

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core, http-post, postman

I have this action on a `.Net Core Web API` Controller called `HomeController`:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult TestMethod([FromForm] DocumentDto xml) {
    int abc = 0;

    return Ok();
}
```

and the model `DocumentDto`:

```cs
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "document", Namespace = "")]
public class DocumentDto
{
    [XmlElement(DataType = "string", ElementName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(DataType = "string", ElementName = "content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(DataType = "string", ElementName = "author")]
    public string Author { get; set; }
}
```

I have also added a breakpoint on the `int abc = 0;` and I use Postman to hit the action as displayed below

[image: Request Headers]

[image: Request Body]

The `xml` used for the request is the following

```xml
<document>
    <id>12345</id>
    <content>This is a Test</content>
    <author>vchan</author>
</document>
```

However, during debugging the `xml` variable has `null` properties as shown below

[image: Debugging]

Also, on the *Startup.cs* file I have included the `AddXmlSerializerFormatters()` and it is as below:

```cs
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Why is the `xml` not parsed?

Comment: Check xmlbounty.Models.DocumentDto which is your input from the test method and see if you are inputting the xml.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with "see if you are inputting the xml"

Comment: Where are you reading the xml?  The issue is not parsing.  You are parsing an empty xml file.

Comment: @jdweng I am not reading it since I am not sending an `xml` file but a string in the request body which should be decoded as `xml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your request the raw XML should be parsed `[FromBody]` and not `[FromForm]`.

Comment: That did it. Now `.net` reads and understands the raw request body. Thank you!